# Send array to the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can i send array to the controller?
I tried so:

```
window.location.href = "/SomeController/SomeMethod?fields=" + SomeArray;
```

and so:

```
window.location.href = "/SomeController/SomeMethod?fields[][]=" + SomeArray;
```

In controller i recieve so:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(int[][] fields) // here fields = null;
{
// Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Convert the js object SomeArray to Json and pass it back to the controller in the data property of the ajax method. Below I use JSON.stringify which modern browsers have support for, but you can include the script [json2](http://www.json.org/js.html) to support older browsers.

```
              $.ajax({
                    url: '/SomeController/SomeMethod',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(SomeArray),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.statusText + " Internal server error")
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Debug the server to find out what the error is. Is your controller action getting called?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, try `jQuery.param`

```
var  data ={

    fields :[
        [
            'car',
            'bike'
        ]
    ]
};

window.location.href = 'SomeController/SomeMethod?'
                       + decodeURIComponent( $.param(data) );
```

Comment: fields has 100 parameters - it's not practical.

Comment: @user2204438 could you show some sample of `SomeArray` contains ? so we can give more specific answer !

Comment: SomeArray[10][10] has int variables {0 or 1 or 2 or 3} it's all